# Getting a table row cell value when a specific column is is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was able to retrieve all row values via table click event and getting its value via `event.currentTarget.cells[4].innerText();`.

But i would like to apply this if a specific column is clicked only like, when i clicked an `ID 21` under `Username column`. It should alert all the cell values of the row. And then when I clicked the other columns it should not alert.

This is my code. Please inform me if you are having problems the way I ask.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tableid').on('click', 'tr', function (event) {
            alert(event.currentTarget.cells[0].innerText);
            alert(event.currentTarget.cells[1].innerText);
            alert(event.currentTarget.cells[2].innerText);
            alert(event.currentTarget.cells[3].innerText);
            alert(event.currentTarget.cells[4].innerText);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my HTML http://jsfiddle.net/jE5UM/

Comment: And what's your HTML?

Comment: Please can you supply a fiddle

Comment: Here my apologies for submitting it late guys. http://jsfiddle.net/jE5UM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tableid').on('click', 'tr', function (event) {                
        $(this).children().each(function(){
            alert($(this).text())
        })
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6NVGC/1/)

If you want an array as the result then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tableid').on('click', 'tr', function (event) {                
        var texts = $(this).children().map(function(){
            return $.trim($(this).html())
        }).get();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6NVGC/2/)

Update

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tableid').on('click', 'tr td:nth-child(2)', function (event) {                
        var texts = $(this).closest('td').siblings().addBack().map(function(){
            return $.trim($(this).html())
        }).get();
        alert(texts.join())
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6NVGC/3/)

Comment: I Appreciate your answer Arun. But what i want is, i want the click event to only work on a specific column like Username. Can you show me how is that possible in qjuery or javascript? Thanks.

Comment: Arun, you are almost there. Can you loop through the row cells and alerting it one by one? I am just new in java scripting that's why. Almost perfect arun.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, in the absence of specific HTML and other information:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tableid').on('click', 'tr', function (event) {
        var cell = event.target,
            values = $(cell).siblings().addBack().map(function(){
                         return $(this).text();
                     }).get();
        alert(values);
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jE5UM/1/).

References:

- [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer. I know your code might be useful in optimization way. But what i want is, I want to make it work only when a specific column is clicked like username. Can you provide me a sample code? Please make a sample work that when i click  a field under username it should alert else no more alert.